# UITextView with supporting @ without spaces to put usernames

Tags: ios, uitextview

Hello I want to implement a control where I want to enable when user type @ character until not fills space in running text it should show list of user and typed text after @ sign should show suggestions based on keyboard characters like we see on twitter or vine like apps ?

could any one give a path to achieve this and if possible the text showed with @name can be different color ?

Thanks I really appreciate if some one give sample code to implement above mentioned functionality.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

When @ is entered you can do you desired actions

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
if([string isEqualtoString:@"@"])
{       
//do twitter like actions
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks yea that m doing using shoudchange delegate but I have requirements where in running string while user is typing if typed @ sign it should detect it and should show some suggestions in table view and that should be selected from list and added after @ sign, user cant type his own if there is @ and after @ if user type space then @ sign shoud be removed itself.
Example text:
Really @riyaz .
so you see on above text my and your name are using @ sign before them that shoud be selected from list instead typing self.